# How to get elements form object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm struggling with my homework. My task is to get a value of an object element, after typing the key of it. The problem is a key, which doesn't exist in the object. In this case it should be 'not found' shown. I don't have any clue how to do this. Idk, if I could explain it right, so I'll show my code and the expected result. I hope you'll check it.

```
  let object = {
  a: "hund", b: "katze", c: "maus", d: "elefant", e: "schlange", f: "stachelschwein", g: "affe", h: "giraffe"
}
function getObjectElements(keys) {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      for (const objectKey in object) {
        if (keys[i] === objectKey) {
          result.push(object[objectKey])
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCM8H.png)

Comment: What's wrong with `const keys = Object.keys(object);` or `const values = Object.values(object);` - That's all you need.

Comment: Look at those methods and the `entries()` method in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#static_methods).

Comment: `Object.values(object)` is *not supported in Internet Explorer*, definitely don't use that.  Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each key take the value from the `object`, and if it doesn't exist (using `??` operator or the `in` operator with a ternary) use `'not found'` instead:

```js
const object = {"a":"hund","b":"katze","c":"maus","d":"elefant","e":"schlange","f":"stachelschwein","g":"affe","h":"giraffe"}

function getObjectElements(keys) {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i];
  
    result.push(object[key] ?? 'not found'); // or key in object ? object[key] : 'not found'
  }
  return result;
}

const result = getObjectElements(['a', 'b', 'z', 'c']);

console.log(result);
```

You can also shorten the code by using `Array.map()`:

```js
const object = {"a":"hund","b":"katze","c":"maus","d":"elefant","e":"schlange","f":"stachelschwein","g":"affe","h":"giraffe"}

const getObjectElements = keys => keys.map(key => object[key] ?? 'not found');

const result = getObjectElements(['a', 'b', 'z', 'c']);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable with the [ternary operator i.e., `?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) or the [nullish coalescing operator i.e., `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (or you have not learned either yet in your course, and you think using them would be unexpected), a simple else branch statement that appends `"not result"` to the result in the case when the object does not contain the key, should make the tests pass:

```js
const object = {
    a: "hund", b: "katze", c: "maus", d: "elefant", e: "schlange", f: "stachelschwein", g: "affe", h: "giraffe"
}

function getObjectElements(keys) {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        const key = keys[i];
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result.push(object[key]);
        } else {
            result.push("not found");
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getObjectElements(['a', 'b', 'z', 'c']));
console.log(getObjectElements(['a', 'a_1', 'a_2', 'a_3', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```